# Typescript function object parameter changes return type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I've been struggling trying to make an object parameter influence the return type of a function.

## Main problem

Here is an example with a `createArray` function to show you what I mean.

```js
interface Selectable { selectable: boolean; }

interface SelectableReturn { selected: {value:any, index:number} }

interface Distant { distant: boolean; }

interface DistantReturn { distances: number[]; }

// All possible type combinations (all objects we can pass to the function)
type Possibilties = Distant | Selectable;

// Here we create the function definitions
declare function createArray(arr: any[], options?: undefined): any[];
declare function createArray(arr: any[], options?: Selectable): any[] & SelectableReturn;
declare function createArray(arr: any[], options?: Distant): any[] & DistantReturn;
declare function createArray(arr: any[], options?: Selectable & Distant): any[] & SelectableReturn & DistantReturn;
```

In the futur you can imagin adding new options to the object. Can you see how much time you would spend on implemeting this ?
If I have 5 options I'll have to have 5² = 25 function declarations...

What I'd like is to automatically, based on the options type, append properties to the returned array.

## Second problem

As you can see, this code works but when you create an array like so :

```js
const arr = createArray([1,2,3], {selectable: true});
```

You don't get intellisens, it's because of the "Possibilities" interface...
Is there a way to detect the "options" type, deduce the return type AND maintain intellisens ?

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=116&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQDYQWOAjLZAb2QGdNtcCIAuZPAewazhAG5kBfAWACg-QkWIhTosOfFgBKEMAFcoIYmQo4IAEzpEAbnAxzarAJ4AaZKHUQAHjRByAtnmicufAeGjwkyACLBSuODK6v6BYHSMzBCsHDz8vIKeIr6hrGAy8orBqSBIpHR2jtAA2gC6sW68APRVyACCGBjIAA4MpKTA1MhgRs0oCAyOoHBgwAwgpMgAFHpNDHgAVpSTAO79rC1w7d0M3QAWKDByuaPjAJR8PX3IAAptHXjAGKMQkwC8KQFpyAA+aKpULBsSo1ZAACWgKDWyAQUGikH2h2OODGSksMFAwFOEz4lgQGDgcOQRxOqJhcJGEDqUCgcCMMxpdGMZTMDGa2NIAH46Md0aANGcmSAjGVgbw8QSiSSUeNyfCqTS6QyoEKRaVWezUVy6GJKJIIILkMzSsgAGT-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-AgCYzCxFCQuwPjyH9CC12QAAiO52k6J4sWAV5xvaoQvAgWiTOqMDlwOIk4AfOkdko2RKERCaZImRargUw71EvLDdLrLJLvqKyfGQIdBDgMdEk68gJmAoA) is a link to the Typescript playground to play around.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPxK5W) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, let me know what is missing and preferably [edit] your example to demonstrate unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: Hello @jcalz. Thanks for the reply. I've looked at your code and learnt some stuff from it. I didn't know how the Partial typescript interface worked. Thanks. Although I'm not quite sure that it's what I'm looking for. Maybe I haven't shown enough details to my problem. I've edited my post and added a link to the code I've created on the playground (I can't add it in the comment section because the url it too long).

Comment: Hmm, now you're outputting the *intersection* of return types instead of the *union*, and you're also intersecting some generic type `T` that has no inference site (how does that `T` get specified when you call `createArray()`)?  I could probably give the intersection instead of the union easily enough, but the `T` thing is just weird and seems unrelated to the question you're asking about.  I was kind of hoping that if you had a problem with my implementation you'd point of something specific about it that needed changing instead of widening the question scope. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Maybe the issue with my code had to do with Intellisense?  If so [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDzAzW) might be better.  If that works for you I'll write it up, and hopefully you'll save the intersection-instead-of-union and uninferrable-generic-`T` for some future question. Let me know.

Comment: I believe I was trying to make my code clearer for people to understand. But I might have failed in doing so if you say that the second part seems unrelated (sorry). I was focusing only on the object sent as a parameter in the first part. I should have specified my problem from the start.

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your second answer, I see what you did. But I believe that the createArray example is as close and clear as I can get to my real example (I can't publish it because it depends on so many things...). I'd like to be able to use properties on an array based on the "options" object parameter. Inside The interfaces (the ones which intersect with options and the return type intersections) do not have the same name and structure in my current code. But they do take a generic type T. You can imagin Distant<T> and DistantReturn<T> for example.

Comment: If you want to change your question so that the stuff in your edit is required, then you should probably refactor the whole thing to show one code example that addresses everything you care about, instead of two different pieces of different code.  And if you do that, you should work on making that code a [mre] without anything unrelated or undefined, and if it's not implemented (like stuff with `T`) then you should remove it.  I am willing to write up my current stuff as an answer if you remove the edit.  Otherwise I may or may not come back later when the question is 
cleaned up.

Comment: I'll try cleaning the question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Just to make it clearer @jcalz. I left the `T` since it shows that you can only pass an array into the createArray function. The createArray function will then return a new Array with the correct appended properties (based on "options")

Comment: You could make the array some specific type instead of generic, though, right?  Is the crux of the question about *generic array subtypes* or is it about having a function parameter affect the return type of the function?  You could just make it `Array<Foo>` for some `Foo` interface.  And if the implementation is just like "imagine we did this thing"over and over again I'm not sure that it's particularly useful; why not just have the whole thing `declare`d so I don't care about implementing it either.

Comment: Every piece of your example code is something the answer has to either *address* or *ignore*, which is why it's good for it to be a [mre] with emphasis on "minimal".  Stack Overflow is also for future seekers to find answers to their questions without having to ask new ones, so having a question not include specific details that you're not really asking about is a service to those people as well.

Comment: I did my best to follow your indiciations. Do you like the way I refactored it ?

Comment: What do you think about [this](https://tsplay.dev/w14aYW) instead?  I believe it has the important piece you are really asking about (looks meaningfully at title of question) without distractions like implementation details, extra generics, and unions-and-intersections (btw, `A | B | (A & B)` is going to be equivalent to `A | B` in almost all situations; I'd be interested in seeing cases where that doesn't hold true for you).

Comment: And [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJR1lW) is how I'd answer that version of the question; note that you can add new input/output relationships easily like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wenLEN) without having it scale badly like overloads.

Comment: Thats amazing ! I have a little other request. What if I just want to check if the option (for example "selectable") is present. I'm saying this because I'd also like to have selectable be an object like so : `{ selectable : { index : 0 } }`.

Comment: I changed the question to match what you told me. Don't hesitate to give other feedbacks about the way I'd introduce people to the problem, I'm also happy to help others if they get stuck.

Comment: You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG6Xvm) if you have input properties that aren't just `boolean`.  Is that okay?  If you need that in the question/answer I can do it, but I'm getting a bit fatigued with scope creep.  Maybe we leave this alone and you can ask questions in a new post in the future instead of followup comments?  Let me know, and I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That's exactly what I am looking for. Thank you for your time and effort in helping me solve this and hopefully help others by clarifying my problem. Yes, I'll create another post if needed. Thank you again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I'd take here is to make a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature that uses the type of the `options` input parameter to produce an output type of the desired shape, which will be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the result types corresponding to each key in the `options` parameter.

One thing that will help here is to define a type `CreateArrayOptions` representing the mapping of input option keys to output return type, so that we can programmatically determine the result type as a function of the options key:

```
interface CreateArrayOptions {
  selectable: SelectableReturn;
  distant: DistantReturn;
}
```

And instead of using the types `Selectable` and `Distant`, we will just map the keys of `CreateArrayOptions` to `boolean` properties... well, actually just `true`, since I don't want to worry about or even support someone setting an option to `false`.  Ideally you just wouldn't include the option instead of setting it to `false`... if you *need* to support `false` it is possible but more complicated.

That means the `createArray()` call signature will look something like this:

```
declare function createArray<K extends keyof CreateArrayOptions = never>(
  arr: any[], options?: Record<K, true> 
): any[] & Return<K>;
```

where the generic type parameter `K` is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keys of `options` (or `never` if `options` is not passed in).  And `Return<K>` should be the intersection of the corresponding `*Return` types.

Here's how to calculate that:

```
type Return<K extends keyof CreateArrayOptions> =
  { [P in K]: (x: CreateArrayOptions[P]) => void }[K] extends
  (x: infer I) => void ? I : never
```

It might not be obvious that this will produce an intersection.  If you wanted a *union*, you could do this very simply as `CreateArrayOptions[K]`, because indexing into an interface with a union of keys produces a union of values.  But to make an intersection programmatically from a union of keys requires a bit more type juggling.  Intersections get generated automatically for you when you [use `infer` in a conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) in a *contravariant* position with multiple inference candidates.  And one such position is the parameter to a function, assuming you're using [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) (which also documents what I mean by "contravariant", but could also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411491/2887218) too).

For the keys passed in we create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where we put the corresponding `*Return` type in a contravariant position and then `infer` the union of these types, which spits out an intersection.  This is also the same general approach used to [turn a union into an intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/2887218).

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const regularArray = createArray([]) // any[]
const alsoRegularArray = createArray([], {}) // any[]
const distantReturn = createArray([], { distant: true }) // any[] & DistantReturn
const selectableReturn = createArray([], { selectable: true }) 
  // any[] & SelectableReturn
const distantAndSelectableReturn = 
  createArray([], { selectable: true, distant: true }) 
  // any[] & SelectableReturn & DistantReturn
```

Looks good!

And it scales easily enough; all you have to do is add more entries to `CreateArrayOptions`:

```
interface CreateArrayOptions {
  selectable: SelectableReturn;
  distant: DistantReturn;
  thirdThing: ThirdThingReturn;
}

const somethingElse = createArray([], { thirdThing: true, distant: true });
// const somethingElse: any[] & DistantReturn & ThirdThingReturn
somethingElse.monkeys // boolean
somethingElse.distances // number[]
```

---

For your final problem, if IntelliSense isn't working for you, it seems to be a bug or design limitation or missing feature in TypeScript where the generic type prevents producing reasonable IntelliSense completion lists. There are lots of issues in GitHub around IntelliSense shortcomings but I don't know if I've found one that's exactly this problem.  Like, [microsoft/TypeScript#28662](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28662) looks related but not obviously identical.  Anyway, in [microsoft/TypeScript#28470](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28470), there is [a comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28470#issuecomment-445402567) that shows a workaround, and translating that here yields the following call signature:

```
declare function createArray<K extends keyof CreateArrayOptions = never>(
  arr: any[], 
  options?: Record<K, true> & Partial<Record<keyof CreateArrayOptions, true>>
): any[] & Return<K>;
```

We want `options` to be seen as assignable to `Partial<Record<keyof CreateArrayOptions, true>>`, which for the original version of `CreateArrayOptions` looks like `{selected?: true; distant?: true}` ([the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) makes all properties [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties)), but still let us infer `K`.  That intersection does both for us.

So now you should get some IntelliSense which at least knows about the expected keys, which should look something like this:

```
// createArray([], { })
// ---------------> |
// ◾ distant   (property) distant?: true | undefined
// ◾ selectable (property) selectable?: true | undefined
```

or for those who can see images:

[image]

Hooray!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQDYQWOAjLAJQjAFcoRkBvZAZ020gBMAua5ANzg1IjbhABPADTJQTCAA82IUgFs80ZAF8VAKFCRYiFABFgtXOGJkK7JgaNJaM+YqgBtALoBudZujwkyACoALYCgmf1AAcxNySho5AHsQAGsIQRtkPBiYrAE3ZTVcj21vAGEoCDhIAEEoKDhBAHkABzBgONpqNWQ6Bhx8LDZ0LG6CCAiKF3bkC0MBMDZ9KeMSSLHkAHoV5DAAoJCQULYQ7YDdkZAxnLUwQXqUE4AeAGlkKUgQJlbEwRiYZGLSiqqag0mi0AHzIAC84xoDgACmJKPcnGwABTSH4lMoQSrVOqNZogWiwpwASghYI4MWATBUDkRT0kLze41RbFAMCUAElSeDyZTqQB+ZAc5AyCAcaC5CQIDBwErIGCkEA4fHIBAY-44h70xnvJJfdF-LEA3HAgkQ5AgMXQEHI8ayqD8ITOUQxPEtflsYgIGJBB6iMBQXhggBkyBhsqa3FuXp9TFuH31v0x2MBboJ-sDEBBILUxMdgmcyFDd3uILGam9BLAyBKoVIMqgKcE5rVhqbyOcpLWyAEBacFZa1e4tBixDrDabLfVRpxHacoioyi7617zgHVYmlmmJynbeNc4Xm-mMw2mZUy57TqcReQcyMYBO68MnQGuCGO-Bqun7ed7Hor56PhT14c9VhXK8b36RhAMfStn0me9yleKDBiIRYzE-Vtk33X8aH-aChjYANeFEBDpiIs8lzAy8+0gro3zQ0xKFDO9t3QkBck4uDqxHOQSCOUIAFEMHoXdsNnXCNi2YIBIokij3vOSUCXMZu24ugYj4zYwmE+h80LFitwWJibwOGSwkfXj+J0kSIAAOliBIklabs0gyUoOKs7Tdl0+yyKVCAXPWWQFGgNc1DU78cPndglwi9YAFokuSlLUrBAAfeLkEAP9IFOmDpkGReooFdaBLlJfywA9YCUHS5BFQkGBQAgJgsty-DUJQIqSuuKBypfAisGq4javq14ICay1qSAA)

Comment: Amazing ! I don't know why though but when I added another generic type to the createArray function, the typing doesn't work. Do you know why that is ?
[Here](https://tsplay.dev/m3ao1w) is the code I experimented with.

Comment: I created a new question that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70191794/typescript-2nd-generic-type-changes-when-1st-generic-type-is-specified)